# Conditionally set a GridViewColumn Cell Template

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I have a view DisplayTestsView.cs and in that view I have

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding SelectedTechnician.Tests}"
SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedTest}" x:Name="AvailableTestsListView" Height="140">
    <ListView.View>
        <GridView>
            <GridViewColumn Header="Id" Width="auto" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Id}"/>
            <GridViewColumn Header="Test" Width="auto" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding TestTypeName}"/>
            <GridViewColumn Header="Status" Width="auto" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding StutusTypeName}"/>
        </GridView>
    </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```

I want the TextColor of the StatusTypeName Cell text to be a certain color based on a condition. For example, if the StatusTypeName equals "Incomplete" then I would like the text in the cell turn red.

The list of Tests (entities) as one can see from the view is the SelectedTechnician.Tests and SelectedTechnician is a property on my ViewModel (DisplayTestsViewModel.

I imagine one has to work with the CellTemplate property on GridViewColumn, but having little insight in how to conditionally manipulate Templates (in general), I am not sure where to start.

Even if the CellTemplate has nothing to do with it how can I coniditionally set the text of a GridViewColumn's cell to change color based on a condition as similarly described above?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are correct that the CellTemplate is the right place for implementing a color change.

You could do something like this (warning - untested):

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding SelectedTechnician.Tests}"
SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedTest}" x:Name="AvailableTestsListView" Height="140">
    <ListView.View>
        <GridView>
            <GridViewColumn Header="Id" Width="auto" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Id}"/>
            <GridViewColumn Header="Test" Width="auto" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding TestTypeName}"/>
            <GridViewColumn Header="Status" Width="auto">
                <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBlock
                            Text="{Binding StatusTypeName}"
                            Foreground="{Binding StatusTypeName, Converter={StaticResource StatusTypeNameToBrushConverter}}" />
                    </DataTemplate>
                </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
        </GridView>
    </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```

`StatusTypeNameToBrushConverter` would be something like this:

```
public class StatusTypeNameToBrushConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(
        object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        var statusTypeName = (string)value;
        switch (statusTypeName)
        {
            case "Incomplete":
                return Brushes.Red;
            default:
                return Brushes.Black;
        }
    }

    public object ConvertBack(
        object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Comment: Would it be possible then to store this logic for the StatusTypeNameToBrushConverter in a ViewModel? If not, could something like this be accomplished with triggers alone? I just read about them on the way home from work. Thanks for the great help so far.

Comment: Actually, ignore the comment above, I got it all figured out and your answer in fact works right out of the box. I added a user control resource dictionary to qualify the location of the StaticResource you created.

Comment: Dont forget to bump / upvote my question if you thought it was well written or well researched in how I presented it. I always like to know when I am doing something right.

Comment: Glad you got it working. I actually see nothing wrong with putting the converter logic in your ViewModel, though this is somewhat controversial. Some think the view model should be agnostic about view-specific concerns such as brushes, sizes, line thicknesses, etc., while others think the view model's job should be to prepare *all* the data needed by the view. I usually feel it's less cumbersome to put everything in the view model (particularly if you find yourself needing multi-value converters), though writing converter classes does enable easy re-use. P.S. I +1'd your question.

Comment: I put the converter in its own class and not in the ViewModel, I am starting to feel some ViewModel bloat as it its. Your point about the controversy surrounding this practice is certainly well justified, and  I am noticing situations such as these really force one consider what layer has what responsibility. And thanks for the +1. Its hard getting rep if one just asks questions :)

Comment: You might want to look into Fody.PropertyChanged (https://github.com/Fody/PropertyChanged/wiki). It basically saves you from having to write INotifyPropertyChanged plumbing, which makes view models much cleaner and easier to maintain.